# Unity Jagged Array Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: unity-game-engine, indexoutofboundsexception, jagged-arrays

I have created a long jagged array full of strings, but am getting an index out of bounds error on the line it is introduced despite the fact that I can create another smaller array just fine like below

```
string[][] testingout = new string[][]
        {
            new string[]{"testing1","testing2"},
            new string[]{"testing3","testing4"}
        };
```

I cannot reference or debug to view anything within the array.
I have manually inputed the correct sizes for the array, and made sure nothing inside or outside the script is referencing the code, but still get this error.  I have tried running this in Start() Awake() and OnEnable
Is this a problem with the code running too slow to initialize all the way because there are so many strings?  My whole array is 20 long and no array inside is longer than 16 long.  Contents are longer than about 5 sentences long.
Thank you for any help provided!

Edit: the error code specifies thats its outside the size of the collection and only happens once it has about 9,000 characters in the array.  I'm Using System.Collection.Generic.  Could that be limiting the size? I don't know how collections work

Edit:  This is the line that the error is called upon (which is when its first mentioned and initialized)

```
 string[][] AlanTalks = new string[16][]
```

Comment: Assuming the missing `"` after `testing2` is just a typo here - could you post the part of the code that actually throws the exception?

Comment: Correct that was a typo in this post.  The array is long and filled with game dialogue so I'm hesitant to post it on here, but I have double checked to make sure it is written as the above example and the added edit above was some more testing I did.  The above array was tested on and fine until I added more numerous and larger string sizes.   this problem persisted even when I made it a list (don't know much about the difference) Thank you!

Comment: What I mean is: I doubt the exception comes from the place where you define (fill) this array ... what you get is a runtime exception when trying to **access** a value from this array => Could you show us the code including the exact line where you get the exception please ... see [mcve]

Comment: If it happens indeed already on declaration time ... then **yes** indeed any array in `c#` has a certain size limit see [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array) `The array size is limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to a maximum index of 0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension (0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures).` .. however your `20 * 16 * 9000` characters are still way below that ..

Comment: Updated to add the line of code the error points to.   I'm genuinely at a loss for why this is happening.

Comment: Again: please post a [mcve] ... otherwise it is hard to reproduce your exact issue ... [I could not](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TvtnTW) neither for declaring nor for accessing the array ;)